# iPhone screen become dark after 30 seconds

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I build an app and i want to disable the auto dark screen, there is a way to cancel it?

i tried this method:

```
[(id)[UIApplication sharedApplication] setBacklightLevel:0.3f];
```

but it's not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just turn off idle timers at all in order to prevent dimming and standby of the device, by:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

later you can/should enable it again (at the time when your app enters background):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
```